# In AL, due to PHB+1, can a player be barred from XGtE spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, dnd-adventurers-league

In AL, if I understand correctly, you can only build your character with 2 books, a PHB and another. If you picked VGM to choose, say, a Firbolg race, then you can't take subclasses from XGtE.

Does that mean that you also can't take spells from that book? You'd only have access to PHB spells?